# AdMob can't get code to work in Androids developer tutorial

Tags: android

I went to
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals
to learn how to ad ads to my app.
It seem really simple, but it tells you to ad
import com.google.ads.*;

this does not work for me, i get the following error 
The import com.google cannot be resolved.

I'm assuming google did not make a mistake in there totuiol, and I'm simply copying the code.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: Did you include the admob jar file in your libs folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto project properties and make sure you are linking the admob.jar file into your project. It can be found in the Android SDK folders. If that still doesnt work, sometime you need to create a lib folder and drag and drop it in there.

Comment: Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs